# Kryonet - connecting from the same IP address (different LAN addresses)

Tags: android, kryo, kryonet

Let's say that I have my TCP server in Germany.

When I try to connect from two mobile phones from Poland in the same LAN network (they have different ip's here):

192.168.1.8 and 192.168.1.14

It disconnects previous device. They both have the same global address, and I don't know how this is happening, cause I store only connections, not the InetAddresses:

```
public ArrayList<Connection> connectionsList = new ArrayList<Connection>();
```

The best thing is that when I open two emulators in the same PC, they work + I can even add one mobile phone O.o.

Any ideas? :(

Comment: 'I store only connections, not the InetAddresses:'. What is a Connection? And why would you store a connection or something?

Comment: 'when I open two emulators in the same PC, they work '. You will have running a client app on those emulators i think.

Comment: Have you used debug level log to log what is going on?